# Create a List Row Heading with below a listView and center each element Flutter web

Tags: flutter

In flutter Web I need to create a List heading and below a listview like the picture I attached but is not well centered, how I can center all the information in the heading with the list below? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use table : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html
Just check this

Answer (score 0):

You should share the code to reproduce. There may be padding on the header of the table or it can be related alignment.